# i3wm dmenu add .desktop file

Tags: i3, .desktop

I wanted to add Android studio to the i3dmenu in: `/usr/share/applications` with the file `android-studio.desktop` containing:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0
Type=Application
Name=android-studio
Exec="/usr/local/android-studio/bin/studio.sh" %f
Icon=/usr/local/android-studio/bin/studio.png
Comment=The Drive to Develop
Categories=Development;IDE;
Terminal=false
StartupWMClass=jetbrains-studio
```

Can somebody tell me why the i3-dmenu still doesn't find android-studio?

I can confirm that the file is readable for everybody.

Comment: Is the file owned by root? (I don't know if it matters or not.)

Comment: Yes it is:
`-rw-r--r--   1 root root   265 Mai 21 13:23 android-studio.desktop`
Like all other `.desktop` files.

Answer (score 5):

For the sake of completeness, `i3-dmenu-desktop` is searching for every binary in `$PATH` and for `.desktop` files in `$XDG_DATA_HOME/applications`[...]. Problem was, the `$XDG_DATA_HOME` variable was not set in my environment.

Comment: if `XDG_DATA_HOME` is not set, it defaults to `$HOME/.local/share`. `i3-dmenu-desktop` also searches any `applications` subdirectories of directories listed in `XDG_DATA_DIRS`, which defaults to `/usr/local/share:/usr/share`, if unset. (Hence `/usr/share/applications`).

Answer (score 3):

dmenu can find applications in `/usr/bin` or `/bin/`

So you can just create a symbolic link to the path of `studio.sh`, which would be

`sudo ln -s /usr/local/android-studio/bin/studio.sh /usr/bin/android-studio`

in your case.

Now you can search for `android-studio` in dmenu to launch it.